# Which is the application that i can open torrent files?

Tags: bittorrent

when i'm trying to download the torrent file to download some video,it was asking me select the application to open that torrent file.

Could you pelase help me on that

Comment: I was unable to find that application....any idea where it will be located?

Comment: that i'm aware but..when i download the torrent file, it was opened a dialog box and asking to select/locate the application which i can open with..

Answer (score 1):

There is [Transmission](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=transmission), which is a GUI application or [rtorrent](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rtorrent) for the command line.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of really good bit torrent clients for Ubuntu out there. Here we intend feature a collection of 5 really good bit torrent clients for Ubuntu which we think are among the best.

**Deluge Bit Torrent Client**
Deluge is among my favorite bit torrent clients for Ubuntu. It is fast, slick and packed with all sorts of functionalities. Deluge is not available in Ubuntu by default, but its in the repositories.
[image]
To install `sudo apt-get install deluge`

Now, if you want to install the latest bleeding edge version of Deluge instead, you need to do the following in Terminal.
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deluge-team/ppa
    sudo apt-get update 
    sudo apt-get install deluge

**Transmission Bit Torrent Client**
As you all should know already, Transmission is the default bit torrent client in Ubuntu for a long time now. Transmission is a nice mix of simplicity and functionality. And it is my second favorite bit torrent client(after Deluge). It incorporates all the basic features you would expect from a torrent client.
[image]

To install `sudo apt-get install transmission`

Transmission is available by default in Ubuntu. But if you want to install the latest bleeding edge version of browser in Ubuntu, you need to do the following in Terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:transmissionbt/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**qBittorrent Bit Torrent Client**
The qBittorrent project aims to provide a Free Software alternative to µtorrent. Additionally, qBittorrent runs and provides the same features on all major platforms including Linux, Mac OS X and Windows. Like the ones we featured before, qBittorrent is also available in Ubuntu repositories by default.
[image]
To install `sudo apt-get install qbittorrent`

Now, if you want to install the latest bleeding edge(and unstable) version of qBittorrent instead, you need to do the following in Terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hydr0g3n/qbittorrent-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

**KTorrent Bit Torrent Client**
This is not really a tailor made bit torrent client for Ubuntu GNOME. KTorrent is a KDE application and it looks complete out of place in a GNOME desktop. But apart from that, from a functionality point of view, KTorrent is a more than adequate torrent client of Ubuntu.
[image]

To install `sudo apt-get install ktorrent`

You can install latest version under development version of KTorrent instead via Kubuntu backports PPA(though I haven't tried it myself).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ktorrent
```

**Vuze Bit Torrent Client**
Vuze bit torrent client is also a widely used alternative among Ubuntu users. Though I have never really preferred it over the likes of Deluge or Transmission, I have noticed elsewhere that a lot of Linux users actually prefer Vuze(previously called Azureus).
[image]

To install `sudo apt-get install vuze`

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you're looking for is:

```
/usr/share/applications/transmission-gtk.desktop
```

You can also try:

```
/usr/bin/transmission-gtk
```

Answer (score 0):

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jacob/comm

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install transmission

Comment: that has been installed already...

Comment: that i'm aware but..when i download the torrent file, it was opened a dialog box and asking to select/locate the application which i can open with..